istio virtual service with multiple root paths
i have been on this implementation for a few days now and for the life of me i cannot solve the issue and i am running out of ideas and knowledge, without talking about the level of frustration.
i am using azure api management for my apis. and i have 2 operations as follow:

and api that is set on this path: https://my-api.azure-api.net/ap and have 1 Operation (GET: /) in the frontend and the backend is forwarded to kubernetes internal pod on this url (my-kubernetes.example.com)
and api that is set on this path: https://my-api.azure-api.net/apaks and have 1 Operation (GET: /template/{Id}/languages) in the frontend and the backend is forwarded to kubernetes internal pod on this url (my-kubernetes.example.com)

the above is the apim configuration. While in istio i have the following yaml files:
ap/aks ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apaks-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: istio
  rules:
    - host: my-kubernetes.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: apaks
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my-kubernetes.example.com
      secretName: api-istio-cert

apaks virtual service:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: apaks
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - istio-system/api
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /apaks
      rewrite:
        uri: /template/{Id}/languages
      route:
        - destination:
            host: apaks.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 80
      headers:
        request:
          add:
            x-ms-client-principal-id: "2d85462-b043-5264-adac-3b1061b19eb7"



and apaks destination rule:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: apaks-destination
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: apaks.default.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL

while for the second api i have a similar implamations
ap ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ap-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: istio
  rules:
    - host: my-kubernetes.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: ap
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my-kubernetes.example.com
      secretName: api-istio-cert

ap virtual service
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ap
  namespace: default
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - istio-system/api
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: /ap
      rewrite:
        uri: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: ap.default.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 80
      headers:
        request:
          add:
            x-ms-client-principal-id: "2d85462-b043-5264-adac-3b1061b19eb7"


and ap destination rule:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: ap-destination
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: ap.default.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL

both application (svc) respond on the root path /.
if i apply the apaks alone, i am able to hit on the url
https://my-api.azure-api.net/apaks/template/{Id}/languages

and get back a 200 OK, all good so far.
but if i try to apply the ap yaml, the apks stops working with a 404 and also the /ap respond with a 404.
So my frustration lead me here with the following question:
In a scenario where i have multiple services that respond only on / how can i configure istio to route the traffic correctly to the right destination?
Thank you so much for anyone who can help me out with this and lift this weight, i am totally lost and confused..did i said already frustrated?
If you need anymore details please do not hesitate to ask
